# Wrap group of divs until next class

Tags: jquery, wrapall, nextuntil

I have the following;

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="row morepad">
    <a href="#">Association 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <a href="#">Association 2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row morepad">
    <a href="#">Association 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#">Association 4</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to wrap them into groups as the following separating according to the first morepad.

```
<div class="content">
 <div>
  <div class="row morepad">
    <a href="#">Association 1</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
   <a href="#">Association 2</a>
  </div>
 </div>
 <div>
  <div class="row morepad">
    <a href="#">Association 3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <a href="#">Association 4</a>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

I have tried the following:

```
$('.morepad').each(function() {
      $(this).nextUntil('.morepad').wrapAll('<div></div>');
  });
```

Comment: You need to include source morepad as well, Try `$(this).nextUntil('.morepad').addBack().wrapAll('<div></div>');` `.addBack()` or `.add(this)` should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Jquery**

```
$('.morepad').each(function() {
      $(this).nextUntil('.morepad').andSelf().wrapAll('<div></div>');
  });
```

you need to add addSelf so that it includes both the ends just wrapALl will only include the elements in betweeen

Working [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rffPG/) link

Comment: yeah just saw that addSelf is replaced by addBack in newer versions of jquery

Comment: Excellent. Worked like a charm. Thanks!